# 404 page with React Router (v4)

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-v4

I'm building an app with some relatively complex routing. The reason it's unusual is that I am animating both the route itself and using the route render method, rather than just calling the component.

So my code looks something like this inside `App.js`:

```
// Route 1
<CSSTransitionGroup>
    <Route render=(
        <CSSTransitionGroup>
            // stuff
        </CSSTransitionGroup>
    )/>
</CSSTransitionGroup>

// Route 2
<CSSTransitionGroup>
    <Route render=(
        <CSSTransitionGroup>
            // stuff
        </CSSTransitionGroup>
    )/>
</CSSTransitionGroup>
```

I'm calling this from `index.js` with:

```
<Router>
    <Route render={({location}) => (
        <App location={location} />
    )}/>
</Router>
```

I need to add a "no match" route. Looking at the official docs I should be using the `Switch` method and then placing this route at the bottom. The problem is, I think, because I'm using lots of nesting *and* CSSTransitionGroup, this is not working. It appears that `Switch` depends on having `Route`s immediately listed in order to work.

So my question - how can I create a "page not found" route with this setup?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution to this. I needed to move all of my routes inside *one* CSSTransitionGroup, and then place the Switch inside it, but also pass some location info to it:

```
<CSSTransitionGroup ...>
    <Switch location={this.props.location} key={this.props.location.key}>
        <Route ..>
    </Switch>
</CSSTransitionGroup>
```

Comment: please mark your answer as the solution for future visitors.

Answer (score 0):

Any route that does not have a path will always match. Regardless of whether you're using a switch or not. The following should work fine. However when you put it is important. You'll need to place it with all the top level routes that are created.

```
<Router>
    <Route render={({location}) => (
        <App location={location} />
    )}/>
</Router>
```

If you are finding that other routes are matching, i.e. the root route, you may need to use the exact keyword